# Android MP Chart - Line Chart Error when value in x-axis decreases

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, mpandroidchart, android-graphview

I am facing an issue in plotting my points using a `LineChart` in [MPAndroidCharts](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library in Android.

**Scenario**

I want to make a chart like the image below. I have values for x-axis that might increase or decrease throughout my `ArrayList`.

[image: Sample Image]

**PROBLEM**
I have a list of coordinates which has the x and y coordinates for the plot.
But when the values in X-axis decrease from the previous one it throws an error

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -6
at com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesLine(Transformer.java:178)
```

**MY EFFORT**

My model class that creates list of objects having lat-long

```
public List<DataSetModel> getData() {

    List<DataSetModel> dataSetModelList=new ArrayList<>();
    DataSetModel dataSetModel = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel.setxCoordinate(10.0f);
    dataSetModel.setyCoordinate(10.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel);

    DataSetModel dataSetModel2 = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel2.setxCoordinate(15.0f);
    dataSetModel2.setyCoordinate(15.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel2);

    DataSetModel dataSetModel3 = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel3.setxCoordinate(20.0f);
    dataSetModel3.setyCoordinate(18.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel3);

    DataSetModel dataSetModel4 = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel4.setxCoordinate(23.0f);
    dataSetModel4.setyCoordinate(20.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel4);

    DataSetModel dataSetModel5 = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel5.setxCoordinate(25.0f);
    dataSetModel5.setyCoordinate(18.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel5);

    DataSetModel dataSetModel6 = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel6.setxCoordinate(23.0f);
    dataSetModel6.setyCoordinate(15.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel6);


    DataSetModel dataSetModel8 = new DataSetModel();
    dataSetModel8.setxCoordinate(20.0f);
    dataSetModel8.setyCoordinate(16.0f);
    dataSetModelList.add(dataSetModel8);

    return dataSetModelList;
}
```

The code that I wrote to get the line-chart

```
LineChart chart = findViewById(R.id.LineChartId);

    List<DataSetModel> dataObjects=getData();
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataObjects.size(); i++) {
        entries.add(new Entry(dataObjects.get(i).getxCoordinate(),dataObjects.get(i).getyCoordinate()));
    }

    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Label1"); // add entries to dataset
    dataSet.setColor(R.color.colorSeverityHigh);
    dataSet.setLineWidth(3.0f);
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(R.color.colorSeverityHigh); // styling, ...
    dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);

    chart.setData(lineData);
```

*I even tried ScatterChart, but was unable to connect the dots in that case. Any help is appreciated, thanks*

Answer (score 1):

According to the [library documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#the-order-of-entries), the LineChart only supports ordered values for the x-axis. The functionality you are trying to achieve is not supported.

> **The order of entries**
>
> Please be aware that this library does not officially support drawing
>   LineChart data from an Entry list not sorted by the x-position of the
>   entries in ascending manner. Adding entries in an unsorted way may
>   result in correct drawing, but may also lead to unexpected behaviour.
>   A List of Entry objects can be sorted manually or using the
>   EntryXComparator:
>
> ```
> List<Entry> entries = ...;
> Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());
> ```
>
> The reason why this is required is because the library uses binary
>   search algorithms for better performance only working on sorted lists.

I recommend that you use another library, such as [SparkLine](https://github.com/robinhood/spark)